# Cannot render images in next.js with example "with-firebase-hosting-and-typescript"

Tags: typescript, image, next.js, src

I set up next.js project with **firebase hosting and typescript**. 
And I installed the Material-UI.

Then, I tried to render my image.
According to following example.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

My Images put in "public" directory directly under "root" directory. It's like "/public/my-image1.png"

And my source code is...

```js
import App from '../components/App';
import { 
  Container,
  Avatar,
} from '@material-ui/core';

export default () => (
  <App>
    <p>Index Page</p>
    <Container>
      <img src="/my-image1.png" alt="hoge" />
      <Avatar src="/my-image2.png" alt="fuga" />
    </Container>
  </App>
)
```

Both of `<img>` and `<Avatar\>` don't render my image.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You can check if you have any other files/directories named public as you example page stated: 'Note: Don't name the public directory anything else. The name cannot be changed and is the only directory used to serve static assets.' Also you can verify request/response in network tab in devTools

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bsekula. Very critical advice. As you indicated, I had another "public" folder in "src" directory. So, I deleted it. But, it could not render. And I verified reuquest/response in network tab. I confirmed the Status 404 about my image. Can you come up with other solution? or notice my overlooking?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Firebase Hosting, in conjunction with Next.js and TypeScript, may encounter issues with rendering images due to some experimental features. To resolve this, consider adding the following configuration to your next.config.js file:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export", // (optional) Set your desired output configuration
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

The key addition here is setting images: { unoptimized: true }, which can help address the image rendering problem. This tweak might be necessary as Firebase Hosting and Next.js are evolving, and certain features may still be in an experimental stage.

I hope this resolves the issue for you. If you encounter further challenges, feel free to provide more details for additional assistance.

Comment: Out of ALL the articles out there I tried this specific one was the winner, thank you:

images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },

Answer (score -1):

I am not `nextjs` guy, but if you deployed your images to `firebase hosting`, these images should be available under `https://{yourFirebaseProject}/my-image.png` (if you put them directly in root directory).

As stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) default root directory is `public`.

> The default for the public root directory is called public.

e.g.

[image]

In this case `<img src="/my-image1.png" alt="hoge" />` you should be able to get images as long as you are trying to get them from files served from your hosting environment (i.e. your html file from `https://{yourFirebaseProject}`)

If you are running on your local environment you can get these images directly from `firebase hosting` like:

```
<img src="https://{yourFirebaseProject}/my-image.png" alt="">
```

If you put your images under different folder in your root firebase folder, you need to adjust url accordingly.

If you do not want to change `src` attribute for your `loclahost` and `firebase hosting` environment, you should have some post-build process which will copy your files from `localhost/public` to `firebase-hosting/root`.

e.g. 
On localhost put your images to `public/images` and after build, copy them to `firebase-hosting-root/images`

In that case you should be able to get these images using the same `src` (once from local environment and once from files served by firebase)

```
<img src="/images/my-image.png" alt="my image" />
```

Good luck!